# Combine multiple command line commands into one single command (pipeline)

Tags: imagemagick

How do I combine the following ImageMagick command line commands into a single instruction:

```
convert -trim "C:\test\test.webp" -quality 95 "C:\test\testMaxNew.webp"
convert "C:\test\testMaxNew.webp" -resize 750x750 "C:\test\testMediumNew.webp" 
convert "C:\test\testMediumNew.webp" -thumbnail 100x100^ "C:\test\testSmallNew.webp"
```

After some trial and error I came up with this:

```
convert -trim C:\test\test.webp -quality 95 -write mpr:XY +delete \( mpr:XY +write C:\test\testLargeNew.webp +delete \)  \( mpr:XY -resize 750x750 +write C:\test\testMediumNew.webp +delete \) \( mpr:XY -resize 100x100^ -gravity center -extent 100x100 +write C:\test\testSmallNew.webp +delete \)
```

This does the trick but the following errors are reported in the command line prompt:

```
> convert: unable to open image '\(': No such file or directory @
> error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert: no decode delegate for this image
> format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert: unable to open
> image '\)': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695.
> convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @
> error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert: unable to open image '\(':
> No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert: no
> decode delegate for this image format `' @
> error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert: unable to open image '\)':
> No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert: no
> decode delegate for this image format `' @
> error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert: unable to open image '\(':
> No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert: no
> decode delegate for this image format `' @
> error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508. convert: no images defined `\)' @
> error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3235.
```

Can someone explain why I am getting these errors and if my code is correct?

The reason I am trying to combine multiple commands is to minimize processing time.

Version: ImageMagick 7.0.2-0 Q16 x64 on Windows 10

Comment: You don't need to escape the opening and closing parentheses with backslashes in Windows. You can remove the backslashes in front of opening and closing parentheses.

Comment: You also don't have an output file at the end which will upset **ImageMagick**. So remove the last `+write`, the last `+delete` and the parentheses around the final part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding an answer to clarify a couple of things that are not a good fit for comments.

You already have some excellent advice from Fred (@fmw42) as regards reading your input image immediately after `convert` because that way your command will continue to work when you upgrade to **ImageMagick** v7 which has already been available a couple of years.

You have added a command that works to your question, but that is a bit clumsy inasmuch as it creates an MPR which you don't need and also creates and destroys images unnecessarily - adding to system load which is undesirable if you have many images to process. I think you can see the following is simpler to understand and maintain, makes fewer copies and deletes and demands on memory, and should achieve the same effect as your command:

```
convert INPUT.webp -trim +repage -gravity center -quality 95 ^
   +write LARGE.webp                                         ^
   -resize 350x350 +write MEDIUM.webp                        ^
   -resize 100x100^ -extent 100x100 SMALL.webp
```

Answer (score 2):

These should do what you want.

Best to read the input right after convert.

I am not sure why you need to resize and thumbnail.

So in Imagemagick try one of the following:

```
convert "C:\test\test.webp" -trim +repage -quality 95 -resize 750x750 -thumbnail 100x100^ "C:\test\testSmallNew.webp"
```

or just

```
convert "C:\test\test.webp" -trim +repage -quality 95 -thumbnail 100x100^ "C:\test\testSmallNew.webp"
```